# Include NULL arrays only from processing in Azure data factory Dataflow

Tags: azure-data-factory

For the below json input, i am trying to include records with NULL array only from within the dataflow, but not sure what am i missing. Any recommendations on how to resolve this.

```
{
    "previous": "https://previouslink.com",
    "results": [
        {
            "TM_Sent": false,
            "appt_check": false,
            "custom_checks": [
                {
                    "custom_type": 998,
                    "Type_value": "East"
                },
                {
                    "custom_type": 4466,
                    "Type_value": "Toyota"
                }
            ],
            "deleted_flag": false,
            "id": "2A457fytg79",
            "tele_url": null
        },
    {
            "TM_Sent": false,
            "appt_check": false,
            "custom_checks": [
                { }
            ],
            "deleted_flag": false,
            "id": "2523DC",
            "tele_url": null
        }
    ],
    "next": "https://nextlink.com"
}a
```

So the expectation, is that within the dataflow only the arraw with id = 2523DC should pass through.
Basically, i have the a flatten component on the custom_checks, which inadvertently is not allowing those with NULL custom_checks to pass through, so i have a new branch kickoff and want to pass just NULL array, which i'll add to the sink at the end.

I tried isNull(custom_checks), but none pass through. I tried creating a derived column and then a filter ,as  in
Derived column iif(length(custom_checks.custom_type) <2, 'yes', 'No'). But they dont work.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to include records with NULL array only from within the dataflow.

To achieve your scenario, you need to flatten the `custom_checks` and based on the values of **custom_type, Type_value** you need to filter the rows.

Follow below steps to achieve your scenario:

1. Flatten the result array using flatten transformation as below.
   [image]
2. Now flatten the **custom_checks** array **along with all columns flattend in previous flatten transformation.**
   [image]
3. Now filter the row if **custom_type, Type_value** using filter transformation.
   Expression: `isNull(custom_type)&&isNull(Type_value)`
   [image]
4. this will give you an expected result, but it will change data type of custom_checks column to complex for this use aggregate transformation to convert it into an array.
   [image]
   [image]

**This will give you appropriate output with correct data type.**

Comment: Thank you for the response. When i follow it, oddly, after step 2 , where i flatten by custom checks, only records that have a value in that array are display, so adding a filter after of isNULL returns no records. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: I have a feeling it might have something to do with the fact the main source file is being treated as a complex, rather than an array, since the source file's json looks like below. 

{"previous":null,"results":[{"TM_sent":false,"appt_check":false,"custom_checks":[{"custom_type":4466,"Type_value":"2"},{"custom_typ